# How to execute external programm in the parent C++ programm in Windows?

Tags: c++, exec

```
int system(const char *str);
    declared in stdlib.h
```

As I know, this code will spawn a new process not within parent process and in Task Manager will be two processes - parent and child.

How to spawn child process in the parent process? ie in Task Manager must be only one - parent - process.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hello. This code is opening new proc, that could be seen in Task Manager, and not only process of the parent programm:
Имя ИД процесса Состояние Имя пользователя ЦП Память (частный рабочий набор) Командная строка Описание

TOTALCMD.EXE 6616 Выполняется ArtUrlWWW 00  3 400 К c:\\Art\Apps\\totalcmd_new\\TOTALCMD.EXE Total Commander 32 bit

|

Имя ИД процесса Состояние Имя пользователя ЦП Память (частный рабочий набор) Командная строка Описание

ExecExternalProgramm.exe 6308 Выполняется ArtUrlWWW 00  348 К ExecExternalProgramm.exe  c:\\Art\Apps\\totalcmd_new\\TOTALCMD.EXE ExecExternalProgramm

Comment: Generally you can't hide process in task manager and I think it is good. But there are some methods to hide your process like DLL injections or [DKOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713467/irp-mj-device-control-to-hide-a-process/32293511#32293511)